# Installing Ubuntu with a DVD on a Mac

Tags: installation, mac, disk-utility

I tried burning a dvd with Ubuntu on it and every time I put it in my computer it says it cant read it. I don't think it's downloading a version for Mac but I just got it from ubuntu.com. I think it may be downloading as the windows version or something because I tried burning it twice and the same thing happened both times. And I'm using a DVD+R incase that matters and I'm burning it with disk utility and I'm using the speed 4x to burn it. And I'm running OS X 10.8.2. What should I do? And I don't what to buy a copy of the cd from the site.

Also is there any reason I shouldn't get 12.10 instead of 12.04?

Comment: 12.10 has some internet related features. I'd just get 12.04

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't burn the DVD correctly. Did you open up the disk utility and clicked on the "Burn" icon and then selected the ubuntu .iso?

Comment: Ya I figured it out. It was downloaded the pc version so I had to find one for mac. But thanks